# Unplugging Alarm System

Tags: electrical, security, alarm

The house I am had an alarm system put in when the house was being built. The previous owners of our house used it but we haven't and all its been is a pain in the butt. Before it would beep when someone opened a door and we were finally able to turn it off. It was also causing a bunch of static noise with our phone line so it was unplugged from the phone line. Now all of a sudden it starting beeping for no reason. I looked on the keypad and could see that there was a problem (or trouble as it says) with the battery, timer, and phone line. I also have a dog has super sensitive ears and was freaked out by the beeping. I followed the manual for it and was able to clear the troubles and it stopped beeping. Now it started beeping again. I got fed up with it and pulled the keypad off the wall and unplugged the connector from the circuit board. I also unplugged the battery in the box as its been sitting in there for over 9 years and is probably dead. I tried to unplug the box but it looks like its wired in with some sort of converter below an electric wall socket where the breaker is and I didn't want to mess around with that. I'm wondering if I unplugged it right? Will the house alarm ever go off now that the keypad is unplugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is designed to dial out on a phone line to a central station or a police monitoring system. These alarms have built in warnings for a failure in the phone line. This is a safeguard so you know the system is not working properly.

So long as the system is operational and cut off from the phone line, it will continue to beep. By removing parts of the keypad and circuit board, you have apparently shut down at least part of the system. If you truly don't want the system on, you need to remove power from the entire system.

The power to the system is probably controlled by master box (probably where the battery was) that has a wire running to a transformer on or near your main power panel. The simplest way to stop the system is to disconnect the wires going from the transformer to the alarm control panel.

The transformer wires are low voltage (usually 24 volts) on the outside (inside the panel they are 120 volts). To be safe, it is better to turn off the breaker connected to the transformer before disconnecting the wire. If you cant figure out which it is, have a flashlight handy, turn off the main breaker, then disconnect the wires. Then turn the main back on.

Once the system is disconnected form both the mains and the battery, it cannot send a false alarm or activate the safety beeper.

Comment: What about the motion detectors? I heard it's better to leave them on in order to deter thieves. If I disconnect the power from the alarm box, will that also shut off the motion detectors?

Comment: Most likely yes. But if you are talking about indoor motion detectors, they don't do anything until you already have an intruder on your property. How do they help? If you want an alarm system to frighten thieves, it is usually possible to remove the dial-out system and have a local only alarm. But you will now need a pro to put back together the sections you broke.